# If a blocking creature leaves the battlefield, is the attacker still blocked, or will it damage the opponent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose Player 1 has a Dragon on the table and [Unsummon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnsummon%5d) in hand, while Player 2 has two Spiders on the table.

Player 1 chooses to attack with the Dragon and Player 2 chooses to block with one of the Spiders.  Before combat damage is to be dealt, Player 1 uses Unsummon on the blocking Spider.

*Does Player 2 take any life damage from the attacking Dragon?*

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**No**

The player takes no damage as the Dragon remains blocked. From [the Comprehensive Rules for the Declare Blockers step](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Declare_blockers_step):

> **509.1h** An attacking creature with one or more creatures declared as blockers for it becomes a blocked creature; one with no creatures declared as blockers for it becomes an unblocked creature. This remains unchanged until the creature is removed from combat, an effect says that it becomes blocked or unblocked, or the combat phase ends, whichever comes first. **A creature remains blocked even if all the creatures blocking it are removed from combat.**

An Exception is, when the attacking creature has trample. See [the Comprehensive Rules for Keyword Abilities](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Keyword_ability):

> **702.19c** If an attacking creature with trample is blocked, but there are no creatures blocking it when damage is assigned, all its damage
>   is assigned to the player or planeswalker it's attacking.

Comment: Basically, your dragon is about to crush a spider when the spider vanishes, leaving the dragon to stare blankly at the space a spider used to occupy.

Comment: But if it's a Charging Badger, it's just like "good, vanished, Imma keep going". Because Badgers do not give a f-

Answer (score 2):

The defender doesn't take damage unless the attacking creature has trample.  This is because the attacking creature is still "blocked" and so must assign its combat damage to its blockers, of which there are none.  The relevant rules are as follows:

> 509.1h An attacking creature with one or more creatures declared as blockers for it becomes a blocked creature; one with no creatures declared as blockers for it becomes an unblocked creature.  This remains unchanged until the creature is removed from combat, an effect says that it becomes blocked or unblocked, or the combat phase ends, whichever comes first. A creature remains blocked even if all the creatures blocking it are removed from combat.
>
> 510.1c A blocked creature assigns its combat damage to the creatures blocking it. If no creatures are currently blocking it (if, for example, they were destroyed or removed from combat), it assigns no combat damage.
>
> 702.19c If an attacking creature with trample is blocked, but there are no creatures blocking it when damage is assigned, all its damage is assigned to the player or planeswalker it's attacking.

Answer (score -3):

In short. Whenever a creature is declared blocked (by declaring a blocking creature), damage will be done to the creature, and not to the player. If something happens (e.g. bounce, sacrifice), the damage is still directed to the creature (which is gone, therefore the damage goes nowhere (creature blocked)).

If the attacking creature has trample, it's a little different. Trample says that all damage more than toughness of the defending creature, continues to the player. Note that with trample, you have to do minimal lethal damage to blocking crature (more is allowed).

Comment: If the creature is gone, the damage is not directed at anything. If there is no blocking creature in play, the attacker remains blocked and does no damage.

Comment: @ColinD I think the idea here was to give the intuitive explanation, the attacking creature tries to deal damage to the blocking creature, but it's not there, so it doesn't do damage. I agree it wasn't precisely stated, though.

Comment: @Jefromi: The problem is that this explanation can easily lead you astray with `lifelink` and other abilities that care about damage—which are quite common.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Not if you think of it the right way: it wants to deal damage to that creature, it's not there, it doesn't deal any damage, so no lifelink.

Answer (score -5):

You wouldn't do damage to the player unless the creature has trample. Abilities like lifelink and double strike still apply. Lifelink requires damage to be done. Doublestrike mearly doubles the damage done. If no damage occurs, neither ability activates. However, if the blocking creature is removed after the damage phase, damage is still done to the blocking creature, although this will remove the damage done and the creature can survive lethal damage. If it's removed before damage can take place, due to a fast effect or instant, no damage is done to the blocker and the attacker is still blocked.

Comment: Most of this answer is entirely incorrect. Double Strike does not just double damage, it causes damage to be dealt twice, in two different combat damage steps. And if a creature takes lethal damage in the combat damage step, it absolutely cannot be saved. Lethal damage is checked whenever any player gains priority, before anyone would even have a chance to cast a spell to save a creature.

Comment: admittedly this was a poorly worded answer and my understanding of double strike wasn't up to par at the time. However, I always believed damage could be avoided with spells and abilities that remove creatures from battle or the battlefield even after combat damage is dealt. But after a quick review of the rules, this is not allowed.