# When should I use Avacyn's Glory's Restoration Angel?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When and how should I use [Restoration Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRestoration%20Angel%5d) in the Avacyn's Glory deck? I understand *Flash* means it can be used any time like an *Instant*. What is the purpose or situation for exiling a non-angel I control then regaining control?

[image: Restoration Angel. Cost: 3W. Flash. Flying. When Restoration Angel enters the battlefield, you may exile target non-Angel creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.]

Comment: Are you perhaps playing Magic as a board game?  This site is for video games, but I can move it to the site for board games if you wish.

Comment: @agent86 I suspect he is playing DotP 2014, but I still think this would be better on BCG as it is about general Magic strategy as opposed to a question about a DotP mechanic.

Comment: This is Magic 2014/DotP on PC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many cards have an ability that triggers when coming into play.  With Restoration Angel, you could re-trigger one such ability.

For the deck you mentioned, [Goldnight Commander](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240029) has the following ability:

> Whenever another creature enters the battlefield under your control, creatures you control get +1/+1 until end of turn

So, when you play Restoration Angel and remove any other creature, your creatures get +2/+2 instead of just +1/+1.  If that other creature is [Geist-Honored Monk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=230787) then the boost to all creatures becomes +4/+4.

This is just one example.  [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fiend%20Hunter), [Champion of the Parish](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Champion%20of%20the%20Parish), [Mentor of the Meek](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244682), and [Soul Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205351) could also be used with this strategy.

Alternatively, you can dodge spells and abilities this way.  If a non-angel you have is targeted by a spell or ability (say [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370654)) then removing the target from play temporarily will cause that spell/ability to miss and do nothing instead.  As @skovacs mentioned in the comments, this can also apply to unwanted enchantments on your non-angel creatures.

Comment: While this is generally right you have it backwards, you can only target ***non***-angel creatures.

Comment: @RalZarek Thank's for pointing that out.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Also, while significantly less useful than activating entry conditions, it could also be used to remove enchantments and debuffs applied to a non-angel creature.

Comment: @skovacs1 great point, added.

Comment: Also if you are attacking and get an unfavourable block you can remove the dude who is going to do from combat with it

Comment: @Gilsham Or, you can block, then have your blocker saved before damage is dealt.

Comment: @PatrickvD [Relevant answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/4169/5137), in case anyone wants to look further into that scenario.