# Can you sacrifice a creature you block with to fulfill Annihilator?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets say someone is blocking an Eldrazi with annihilator. Can they sacrifice a creature they blocked with to count as one of the things sacrifice with annihilator?

Comment: I rolled back the edit made by the author because it totally changed the question being asked. Clarification is good, but editing to ask a different question is usually not. If you have a new question, use the Ask Question button. Unfortunately, the rollback also means that the duplicate closure no longer makes any sense. The question is still a duplicate of [Can you claim a Double Sacrifice Bonus](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5892/6692) (in my opinion). I flagged for moderator attention so that hopefully this can be sorted out.

Comment: Also, this is a good question (even though it's been asked before). I hope you don't delete it again!

Comment: Nominated for reopening. I don't think it's a duplicate of double sacrifice bonus either, because there's question about blocking with the creature and then sacrificing it to annihilator, which as the answer points out isn't possible.

Comment: I removed the second question because we only want one question per question, and the second question is already answered here: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/if-a-blocking-creature-leaves-the-battlefield-is-the-attacker-still-blocked-or?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @diego As I re-read the second question, I'm not convinced it's the same as what you linked.

Comment: @corsiKa 5 other people closed it as a dupe of that one, and regardless it should be asked on its own, not as a part of this one.

Comment: @diego Sorry, they were mistaken, and so are you. It is not a "second question" but rather an attempt to rephrase the first question. It doesn't make sense to people who understand the rules because both phrasings of the question are asked on a faulty premise. This is why it looks like a different question. But it isn't a different question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Annihilator happens before blocks.  When the attacking player declares attackers, the Annihilator trigger goes on the stack.  The defending player has to resolve it first.  Then the phase can move to the Declare Blockers step.  If you still have a creature at that point, you can block.

Comment: okay, let me rewrite the question then.

Comment: @ShadowZ. If you want to ask a different question (including if that different question is what you originally intended), we invite you to ask a new question instead in this case.